# Java Error javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot Found on running a command

Tags: 14.04, server, java, jvm

I was trying to run a software dbvis on linux and found the following error about java

CompilerOracle: exclude javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot

Anh solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, just an harmless Java message that cannot be turned off. It doesn't affect the functionality of DbVisualizer.

Comment: But DBvis failed to start when i run in command line by typing ./dbvis the above message appear only.

Comment: Please use the following link to post a support request: http://www.dbvis.com/company/contact/